# How to make local array a persistent one?

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory-management, delphi-2009, dynamic-arrays

I have a callback procedure:

```
type
  TInitCallback = procedure (var Data: Pointer);
```

The idea is that after initialization `Data` could point to anything.

I've tried to assign this procedure to the callback and init `Data` in a way that it should point to a newly created array:

```
type
  TBoolArray = array of Boolean;

procedure InitData(var Data: Pointer);
var
  BoolArray: TBoolArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(BoolArray, 10);
  for i := 0 to Length(BoolArray) - 1 do
    BoolArray[i] := False;
  Data := BoolArray;
end;
```

However, I am not sure that reference counter is increased for array when assigning: `Data := BoolArray;`. In other words - I am not sure that array is still in memory after leaving the procedure or has it been freed?

Because later in a program execution, when I change the data in some other structure ( a record which has nothing to do with this array), this change makes changes in earlier allocated array(Data).

One explanation for this would be that the memory for array was freed when leaving the callback and reused once again for the record.

So, does the array stays allocated after leaveing InitData callback or not? And if not, how to make it stay allocated. Please not that I do not want to change the signature of my callback, I can not introduce any new params or change it to a function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that the reference count of the dynamic array is not incremented when you assign to `Data`. This means that the local array goes out of scope when `InitData` returns. Thus your code is broken.

The most simple solution would be to change the definition of `TInitCallback` to use a dynamic array and then the reference mechanism would manage the lifetime for you. Since you do not wish to change your interface then you have (at least) the following options:

1. Make `BoolArray` a global variable. That would only work if there is only one instance in your application.
2. Change the type of `BoolArray` to `^TBoolArray` and use `New` to allocate this on the heap. You would also need to add another procedure which would deallocate the array with a call to `Dispose`.
3. Very similary to option 2, wrap the array in a class. Class instances can be safely stored in pointers. Again you would need another function to dispose of the class instance by calling `Free`.